# QGIS - Least Cost Analysis - Removing waterbodies

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, least-cost

I'm new to least cost analysis. I have a DEM-layer of a region, an I also have created slope layer. The purpose is to calculate the least cost path between to ancient sites with QGIS. However, in the region there are lakes and river (I have the Shapefiles), and the problem is that the resulted least cost path crosses through the lakes and rivers and I don't want that. I want them to be constraints, so the paths should find another way to the destination point.

How do I make the least cost tool take them into consideration?

Comment: They must be included in your friction surface. Try rasterizing the water bodies and give them a high dn value.This https://publikationen.uni-tuebingen.de/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10900/61047/39_DeSilva_Pizziolo_CAA_2000.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y describes also an aproach.

Comment: Thanks. I converted my polygon data (waterbodies) into a binary raster where 1 is waterbodies, 0 is nothing, then I use the conversion tool to recode recode the raster so where the raster was 1 recoded to NODATA . Now,  how can I assign the cells where waterbodies would be to NODATA in my DEM and then build the cost distance raster?

Comment: You can use the raster calculator to do a variety of operations. The especific operation is up to you

Comment: Thanks. But in this case (as I'm learning how to use the raster calculator and its language) how could I formulate this specific operation?

Comment: Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCyNRf_olkw.